# How to implement field formatters for entity properties

Tags: 7, entities

I created a custom ***entity*** using ***Entity API*** that has certain properties defined in `hook_schema()` and also declared in `entityPropertyInfo()`, a class extending `EntityDefaultMetadataController`.

So far so good.

Now I'd like for users to be able to customize if and how these properties get displayed when viewing the entities so I implemented [hook_field_extra_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7) and declared them.

Then, in my Controller which extends `EntityAPIController` I added the properties to the $content array in `buildContent()` as, outlined [here](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api).

It actually works pretty well and properties are rendered and respect the order and visibility settings in "Manage Display".

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add settings in Manage Display to customize the label positioning (`inline/above/hidden`) and, more importantly, how to specify custom formatters for these properties.

Any clues?

Comment: Do properties even support formatters? Since "Node" doesn't have "Title" under "Manage display", my first guess would be no. +1 for a good question though.

Comment: Entity properties don't support formatters, no. You would need to implement that whole mechanism yourself

Comment: I was fearing that was the case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a module providing a "`property`" field type. Store the the property to be formatted as an instance setting and then apply a formatter to that. It should be relatively straightforward. [Relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module has a dummy field module which might help you in figuring out how to code this.

Comment: The [Entity Property Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_property_field) module is another starting point for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in `field_ui_display_overview_form` in `modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc` the page `Display setting` will fill with `$instances` and `$extra_fields`:

```
$instances = field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle);
$field_types = field_info_field_types();
$extra_fields = field_info_extra_fields($entity_type, $bundle, 'display');
```

in this function there is two loops which create the page:

```
foreach ($instances as $name => $instance) {
   ...
}
```

and

```
foreach ($extra_fields as $name => $extra_field) {
   ...
}
```

and only in first loop which iterate in fields there is options for `label` and `formatter`

so if you want this functionality on your properties (as @Clive said):

> You would need to implement that whole mechanism yourself